# R locale setting problems on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, locale, r

I'm trying to install packages in R using Mac OS X, but I keep getting `tar: Failed to set default locale` errors for any package I try. After Googling around I found that this was due to unexpected locale settings. I set them back to `en_US.UTF-8` as recommended elsewhere, but still can't install packages. When I run `locale` in Terminal, I get:

> LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

But when I run `system("locale")` in R I get:

> LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_COLLATE="C"
>   LC_CTYPE="C"
>   LC_MESSAGES="C"
>   LC_MONETARY="C"
>   LC_NUMERIC="C"
>   LC_TIME="C"
>   LC_ALL="C"

I do remember setting some locale settings to "C" awhile ago, for some other purpose, but forget where now.

Answer (score 5):

This command seems to fix it:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

After restarting R, no more warnings about the default locale.

Answer (score 0):

NB. There is one more thing that you need to consider after changin "default locale" setting in terminal. Check your code and remove all lines in R that do force to change locale setting while running the code, i.e. delete "Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")" if you use it somewhere in the code. You can check that you have correct settings by running "system("locale")" in R.

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.

Comment: Actually id does. I just had the same problem and just changing default locale wasn't helping. Then I realized that in one of dozens modules in my script I had Sys.setenv function which rewrited default settings.